# How to organize (from highest to lowest) a hand of 5 deck-cards? or how to split an array of strings into sub arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am stuck on how to organize 5 cards from highest to lowest. the 5 cards will come into the method as an array called handDeck, the array would look something like this: {"Ace spades", "Five hearts",...etc}. What I tried is iterate through the array and splitting each element into smaller array contain the first and second word for example: in the example array I wrote earlier, the first sub-array would look like this: {"Ace", "Spades"}. this can allow me to check every first element of those 5 sub-arrays and check which order they should follow. however, I don't know how to implement this sub-array method. i haven't coded in so long so my memory is very shady right now. also if you can give me a hint on how to check the order of the first element of the sub-arrays, that would be very helpful.

the code that I tried is this:

```
String[] deck = {"Ace spades", "Five hearts", "Four spades", "King diamonds", "Queen diamonds"};
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   String s = deck[i];
   s.split(" ");
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You need a `Card` class that has a `suite` attribute and a `rank` attribute. Then you need to implement a `Comparator` in `Card` that can compare two instances of `Card`. To create the `Card` from a string you need a parser to handle an instance of the `String` values you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to compare string names with each other, so that you can determine "Jack" is ranked higher than "Ten" for example, but lower than "Queen". There are a number of ways to this, below is one.

As a first step, here is a map that will allow translating a card name to it's numeric position relative to the other card names. Ace is ranked the highest in position 13, while the Two card is ranked lowest in position 1.

```
static Map<String, Integer> positions = new HashMap<>();
static {
    positions.put("Two", 1);
    positions.put("Three", 2);
    positions.put("Four", 3);
    positions.put("Five", 4);
    positions.put("Six", 5);
    positions.put("Seven", 6);
    positions.put("Eight", 7);
    positions.put("Nine", 8);
    positions.put("Ten", 9);
    positions.put("Jack", 10);
    positions.put("Queen", 11);
    positions.put("King", 12);
    positions.put("Ace", 13);
}
```

Here's a simple usage below. All it's doing is calling `Ararys.sort()` with a compartor that looks up each card name in the `positions` map. Note that the "cards" array is just the card names and not card+suit like you posted (so "Ace", and not "Ace spades"):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] cards = {
            "Ace",
            "Five",
            "Four",
            "King",
            "Queen"
    };

    System.out.println("before sort: " + Arrays.toString(cards));
    Arrays.sort(cards, Comparator.comparing(o -> positions.get(o)));
    System.out.println(" after sort: " + Arrays.toString(cards));
}
```

And here's the output from running that, first it prints the original array, then it prints the same array once more after the contents were sorted:

```
before sort: [Ace, Five, Four, King, Queen]
 after sort: [Four, Five, Queen, King, Ace]
```